# How do I use the AWS CLI to set encrypted Lambda environment variables?

Tags: amazon-web-services, encryption, aws-lambda, aws-cli

I have AWS Lambda environment variables locally that would like to encrypt with a specific KMS key and assign to an Lambda function.

I'd thought that something like

```
aws lambda update-function-configuration --function-name functionName --cli-input-json file://config.json
```

with `config.json` as

```
{
  "Environment": {
    "Variables": {
      "var01": "Variable one",
      "var02": "Variable two"
    }
  },
  "KMSKeyArn": "arn:aws:kms:us-west-1:09238573743:key/...."
}
```

would accomplish this. But the variables end up un-encrypted. The "KMSKeyArn" seems only to be used to decrypt (e.g. within the function's handler with `boto3.client('kms').decrypt`).

How do I use the AWS CLI to take local (unencrypted) values, ideally specified on JSON, and assign them as encrypted values for Lambda function's environment variables using a specific KMS key (and assure that same key is assigned to the function for use by `boto3.client('kms').decrypt`?

I'd also like to be sure that my variables are never transmitted as plain text (that is, that the encryption occurs locally), if possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unlike AWS console that is built to make multiple calls that can span various services, AWS CLI makes a single call. 
That is why `$ aws lambda update-function-configuration` won't encrypt our variables.

Therefore, in order to accomplish this, we just need two commands:

> `$ aws kms encrypt --key-id **** --plaintext "Variable one"`

And then take the cipher text  from the result, and use it as the variable:

> `$ aws lambda update-function-configuration --function-name functionName --kms-key-arn **** --environment Variables={var01=XXXXXXXXX}`

*-- Edit :*

*The key that we can set in argument to the `aws lambda update-function-configuration` command is for the at-rest encryption. (As in the console)*

*For the environment variables decryption, there is no need to tell the lambda which key it has to use, as this information is on the cipher text. But we have to be sure le lambda can get access to the key, by setting in AWS IAM the role of the lambda as a user of the key.*

Comment: Thanks. How do I ensure that the code in my Lambda function can decrypt those variables; simply by assigning the key that matches `****` in the Console under "Configuration > Advanced settings > KMS key"? Or is that setting for some other purpose?

Comment: This is a good question and should have been in my answer : 
This setting is the same as in the AWS CLI : it set the key for the at-rest encryption of the data in your lambda. So it is not used to decrypt your environment variables. 

To be sure your lambda function can decrypt your encrypt variables (ie. it can use your key) you have to go in AWS IAM, to set the role of your lambda as a user of your key.

Comment: That's what's confusing me: it's not clear to me what "at rest" means, as distinct from the encryption performed by `boto3.client('kms').decrypt`, or the encryption preformed with the CLI or "encryption helper" in the Console. (For example, if the variables are encrypted "at rest" — and apparently automatically decrypted without needing to use the KMS API in a function — why bother with any other encryption?)

Comment: I can just say that the 3 types of encryptions you mentioned (SDK, CLI and Console in encryption helper) are the same. 
For the question "In a at at-rest encrpyted environment, is it necessary to decrypt a encrypted variable if the 2 keys are the same ?" I can't say or explain. It should be a new question..